# solving series of matrices by simply multiplication

Tags: matrix

I have a number of matrices `{2*2}` containing element in series ....so by what method I solve that ...

```
mat.{A (i), B (i)} == {A (i + 1), B (i + 1)}
Solve[%, {A (i + 1), B (i + 1)}, {i, 0, 20}]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to solve recursive relations I hope the following is helpful.

Consider the following simple example (I will initial index at 1):

If your aim is to get numerical result

```
mat = {{1, 2}, {1, -1}};
{1, 1}
f[n_] := Nest[mat.# &, {1, 1}, n - 1]
```

If you wish to get analytical solution you can use RSolve:

```
sol = RSolve[{a[n + 1] == a[n] + 2 b[n], b[n + 1] == a[n] - b[n], 
   a[1] == 1, b[1] == 1}, {a[n], b[n]}, n]
```

yields:

{{a[n] -> 
   1/2 3^(-(1/2) + n/2) (1 - (-1)^n + Sqrt[3] + (-1)^n Sqrt[3]), 
  b[n] -> -(1/2) 3^(-(1/2) + n/2) (-1 + (-1)^n)}}

You can then get results, e.g.:

```
r[n_] = {a[n], b[n]} /. First@sol
```

Comparing:

```
Grid[{#, f@#, r@#} & /@ Range[10], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

You can exploit linear algebra for power matrices etc. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Make recursive equation with A(n+1)=A(n) and B(n+1)=B(n) and then use RSolve command.

```
mat = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}};
eq = mat.{A [i], B [i]} == {A [i + 1], B [i + 1]};
eq = Thread[eq]
```

> {A[i] + 2 B[i] == A[1 + i], 2 A[i] + B[i] == B[1 + i]}

```
RSolve[eq, {A[i], B[i]}, i]
```

> {{A[i] -> 1/2 ((-1)^i + 3^i) C[1] + 1/2 (-(-1)^i + 3^i) C[2], 
>   B[i] -> 1/2 (-(-1)^i + 3^i) C[1] + 1/2 ((-1)^i + 3^i) C[2]}}